# Real using of the "Realized GARCH" for 1 minute forecast

Tags: garch, volatility-forecasting, time-complexity

I would like to ask someone who has an experience with the "Realized GARH" by Peter Hansen. I have 2 questions:

1. Is there a logical purpose to use realGARCH for 1 minute forecast?
2. How long could it take to train it using the Student likelihood?

Comment: What do you mean by *using Student's $t$-statistic to define the estimators*? Perhaps you mean using the Student's $t$-distribution for the likelihood function? Also, what are you forecasting?

Comment: Thank`s. You are right. It should be the "Student's t-distribution for the likelihood function". And data - for example, E-mini S&P 500 or Forex pair Euro /US$.